# JavaMe, Send mail via smtp.gmail.com with TLS

Tags: email, java-me, smtp, embedded

I am developing the mail client for Cinterion EHS5 device. This device can run javaMe 3.2
I need to send a mail using  smtp.gmail.com port 587 with TLS.
For now I am able to send email via  smtp.gmail.com with SSL using code like this.

```
SecureConnection sc =(SecureConnection)Connector.open("ssl://"+this.mailAccount.getSMTPserverAddress() + ":"+this.mailAccount.getSMTPport(),Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
```

I tried the examples of Blackberry developers and tons of variations to make it work with TLS.

```
   SecureConnection sc =(SecureConnection)Connector.open("tls://"+this.mailAccount.getSMTPserverAddress() + ":"+this.mailAccount.getSMTPport(),Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
```

Didn't work.

Does anybody know the good approach to solve this problem?
Links, books, examples will be appreciated.